# Deleting user specified text in a text file

Tags: java, arrays, text-files

I am working on a assignment for a class that involves deleting one specific entry from a text file. This is the specific question

> Create a new program that will access your data file ‘phone_directory.txt’ and
>   allow the user to delete one of the names and phone numbers in the data file. To
>   do this you will need to read the data file into an array first (be sure to count the
>   number of records to create an array of the correct size). Sort the data file in
>   ascending sequence. Now when the user enters a name to delete you can search
>   your data file and display the information for the record that fits the name entered

So I already have a previous file that allows the user to input additional names and that code is here:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
{
    c = new Console ();

    int count = 0;

    String[] FirstNames = new String [10];
    String[] LastNames = new String [10];
    String[] PhoneNumber = new String [10];

    BufferedReader input;
    input = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("phone_directory.txt"));

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        FirstNames [i] = input.readLine ();
        LastNames [i] = input.readLine ();
        PhoneNumber [i] = input.readLine ();
        //count++;
    }

    input.close ();
    PrintWriter output;
    output = new PrintWriter (new FileWriter ("phone_directory.txt"));

    for (int k = 0 ; k < 10 ; k++)
    {
        output.println (FirstNames [k]);

        output.println (LastNames [k]);

        output.println (PhoneNumber [k]);
    }
    c.println ("Please enter the first name or end to exit: ");
    String FirstName = c.readLine ();
    while (!FirstName.equals("end"))
    {
        output.println (FirstName);

        c.println ("Please enter the last name: ");
        String LastName = c.readLine ();
        output.println (LastName);

        c.println ("Please enter the phone number of this person (no area code): ");
        String PhoneNumbers = c.readLine ();
        output.println (PhoneNumbers);
        c.println ("Please enter the first name: ");
        FirstName = c.readLine ();
    }

    output.close ();
```

However when it comes to deleting entries I have no idea where to start. I assume I must input them into an array similar to the previous question and then ask the user for a name and if their is a match somehow delete those names from the text file. I am using "Ready to Program" and the language is Java.

Comment: Do you need to output the new phone directory with the deleted record to a text file? Or print it to screen?

Comment: Also, a sample of the structure of the text file would be useful.

Comment: You don't need to print it out to the screen, as long as it changes the text file that is good enough. The text file is formatted as follows: First Name *newline* Last Name *newline* Phone Number *newline* and repeat for 10 names